# What does "qualified this" construct mean in java?

Tags: java, jls

In [Effective Java](http://books.google.co.in/books/about/Effective_Java.html?id=Ft8t0S4VjmwC&redir_esc=y)  inside the item "Item 22: Favor static member classes over nonstatic" Josh Bloch says:

> Each instance of a nonstatic member class is implicitly associated with an
>   enclosing instance of its containing class. Within instance methods of a nonstatic
>   member class, you can invoke methods on the enclosing instance or obtain a reference
>   to the enclosing instance using the qualified this construct.

What does he mean by *Qualified This Construct*?

Comment: `EnclosingType.this`

Comment: In computer science terminology a qualifier, or qualified identifier, is a name (selection path) `x.y.z`. This pre-dates java.

Comment: [Read all about it at the source.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.8.4)

Comment: @pst +1 since you answered in the comment itself. How do I accept your answer?

Comment: @pst Since you were the first to answer, I suggest writing up a short answer. You can paste my link in there, too (from my comment above, it's a JLS link).

Comment: One identifier is hardly an answer -- it needs some context as to *why* it is useful. I do not have enough time to give it justice at the moment.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Without the qualifier, `x()` would recurse. With the qualifier, the enclosing instance's `x()` method is invoked instead.

```
class Envelope {
  void x() {
    System.out.println("Hello");
  }
  class Enclosure {
    void x() {
      Envelope.this.x(); /* Qualified*/
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 11):

A non-static member class has an implicit reference to an instance of the enclosing class. The *Qualified This* term refers to the instance of the enclosing class. If the enclosing class is `A`, and the inner class is `B`, you can address the enclosing reference of `A` from `B` as `A.this`.