# Java Consumer Interface

Tags: java, java-8, functional-programming

someone can help me understand below code from Java 8 Functional Interface 
As per my understanding accept() takes as input and process it but does not return any value then in case of andThen() how it works

> accept() method takes as input the type T and returns no value.

```
default Consumer<T> andThen(Consumer<? super T> after) {
        Objects.requireNonNull(after);
        return (T t) -> { accept(t); after.accept(t); };
}
```

Comment: `(T t) -> { accept(t); after.accept(t); }` is a `Consumer` again which ensures that the current Consumer is `accept`ed first and then the one mentioned as `after` is `accept`ed.

Comment: but accept method is not returning any value then how come we get Consumer?

Comment: @NPE the returned value is the whole thing: `(T t) -> { accept(t); after.accept(t); }`, not the result of the call to `accept(t)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to understand what is getting `return`ed from that API, you can try visualizing the implementation as :

```
default Consumer<T> andThen(Consumer<? super T> after) {
    Objects.requireNonNull(after);
    return new Consumer<T>() { // return the complete Consumer implementation
        @Override
        public void accept(T t) {
            Consumer.this.accept(t); // accept current consumer
            after.accept(t); // and then accept the 'after' one.
        }
    };
}
```

and now relate that

```
(T t) -> { accept(t); after.accept(t); }
```

is a `Consumer` returned which ensures that the current one is `accept`ed first and then the one mentioned as `after`.

Comment: `@Naman` Why we have to do Consumer.this.accept(t)? I did not get this.

Comment: @IfOnly It's a ["qualified this"](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se12/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.8.4), which makes it so the `accept` method of the _enclosing_ instance is invoked. Without the qualification the `accept` method of the current instance (`this`) would be invoked, leading to infinite recursion. It's a little confusing in this case, since we have an anonymous `Consumer` enclosed by another `Consumer`, but it's no different than the example given in [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11276994/what-does-qualified-this-construct-mean-in-java).

Answer (score 1):

A functional interface must have only *one* abstract method. However, it can have as many static and default methods as you'd like. The methods of `Consumer` are:

1. `accept(T)`

   - This is the single abstract method of `Consumer`. It accepts a single generic argument of type `T` and returns nothing (i.e. `void`). This is the method that's implemented by a lambda expression or method reference.
2. `andThen(Consumer)`

   - This is a **default** method. In other words, it has an implementation and is thus non-abstract. The method accepts a `Consumer` and returns another `Consumer`. Since it's a default method, the single abstract method of `Consumer` remains `accept(T)`.

The above explains why `Consumer` can have a method that returns something other than `void`. Now, when it comes to the implementation of `andThen`, it's important to realize there are actually *three* `Consumer`s involved:

1. The instance on which `andThen` was invoked.
2. The instance referenced by `after`.
3. The instance returned to the caller.

If you format the code so not everything is on the same line it may be easier to follow:

```
default Consumer<T> andThen(Consumer<? super T> after) {
    Objects.requireNonNull(after);
    // Returns Consumer instance #3. The lambda is the implementation
    // of the 'accept' method.
    return (T t) -> {
        accept(t);       // Invokes 'accept' on Consumer instance #1.
        after.accept(t); // Invokes 'accept' on Consumer instance #2.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand your concern. You wonder why could you call `andThen()` after `accept()` if `accept()` returns void.

The thing is, that you first define a `Consumer` object, and **on that instance** you call `andThen()` method. For example:

```java
Consumer<String> consumer = s -> System.out.println(s);
consumer.andThen(s -> System.out.println(s.toUpperCase()));
```