# How to differentiate member variable and function variable in kotlin

Tags: java, android, kotlin

```
 class A{
    ..........
    var name:String? // Member variable
    fun doSomeThing(name:String?)//name as function variable
    {
       uiScope.launch{name=name}
    }
    ..........
   }
```

In case of java we use this.name=name, but how to do it in kotlin

Comment: You can do `this.name = name` in Kotlin too...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured out the same in kotline as follows

```
class A{
..........
var name:String? // Member variable
fun doSomeThing(name:String?)//name as function variable
{
   uiScope.launch{this@A.name=name}
}
..........
```

}

Comment: `this@A` instead of `this` should only be needed inside an inner class, where Java would have [`A.this`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11276994/what-does-qualified-this-construct-mean-in-java)

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov I guess inside `CoroutineScope#launch` you get a receiver to a child `CoroutineScope`, so qualified access is required.

Comment: @AnimeshSahu That makes sense, didn't think of it!